# Why does this node-red configuration for websockets work?

Tags: node-red

I have created a node-red websocket connection that sends the following JSON message

{"event":"subscribe","channel":"trades","pair":"BTCUSD"}

to the Bittrex websocket:

wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws

[image]
I also created a websocket that listens to the same address

For some reason it works. I'm confused since there is no relationship that I can see between the websocket that sends the payload with the one that receives the data and sends it to debug (green).

Does anyone have any insights on this please?

Answer (score 2):

When you configured the first WebSocket node, you would have created a new 'websocket-client' node under the URL field with the ws:// url. That websocket-client node is what creates the underlying connection.

When you configured the second WebSocket node, you must have reused the same websocket-client node. That means the two nodes share the same connection.

If you wanted them to use different connections to the remote end, you would give the second WebSocket node a new websocket-client node (Select 'Add new websocket-client...' in the URL select box).

Comment: Understood. I think I need to use this 'approach' even though I don't want to for two reasons:

Comment: I think I need to use this 'approach' even though I don't want to for two reasons: (1) i want to include a json message as the payload in the websocket connection request. the connection at the top allows this but does not have an output so i cannot see what is returned; (2) the websocket connection at the bottom allows me to see the output but i cannot send a json payload. is it possible to do what i want (send payload with json request as part of connection AND see output) with only one websocket module? if that makes sense.

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. What you have is what you want. The two nodes represent the same connection, one for sending to it, the other receives from it. So you send your json to the top node and you get the response back in the bottom node.

Comment: Ok understand now. In other tools I used to do (slightly similar) things there was a connection between the two points. I am working on building a capability to pull data from multiple streams and put into Mongo for analysis. This helps a lot. Will publish on github.com and share in this post when done.